# retrieve mysql data using jquery and php

Tags: php, jquery, mysql

I have tried this and works fine on my localhost but on the server 000webhost.com it does not work. Also the Jquery does not work in IE but the other browsers. it is IE 10

What I would like to do is have the the user select a province from a `<select>` and then based on the province selected the cities for that province must be loaded into another `<select>`

here is the relevant jquery:

where '#searchProvince' and '#searchCity' are the  two `<select>`

```
var province = "";
    $("#searchProvince").on("change",function(){
        province = $("#searchProvince").val();


        //Retrieve all cities under the province
        $.post("phpScripts/get_cities.php",{province: province}, function(output){
            results = $.parseJSON(output);

            $("#searchCity").empty();

            $("#searchCity").append("<option value=\"" +results[0]+ "\" selected=\"selected\">"+results[0]+"</option>");

            for(i = 1; i < $(results).length; i++)
            {
                    $("#searchCity").append("<option value=\"" +results[i]+ "\">"+results[i]+"</option>");
            }
        });
    });

});
```

then when this is passed to the php page get_cities.php

```
<?php
    $city = array();
    if(isset($_POST['province']) === true && empty($_POST['province']) === false)
    {
        $province = $_POST["province"];
        require "connect.php";

        $query = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT DISTINCT city FROM _tblGeo WHERE province = '".$province."'");

        $i = 0;
        while ($row = mysqli_fetch_row($query))
            {
                $city[$i] = $row[0];

                $i++;
            }

    }
    echo json_encode($city);
?>
```

Comment: What is the error ? Is it calling the server correctly ?

Comment: Did you update your `connect.php` file to include the new server details for the MySQL server on 000webhost? It won't be localhost. Use the domain/user/pass they give you.

Comment: Hi I have tested it on freemyslq hosting and found that the problem was my SQL query the data is only is "small" letters hence _tblGeo should have been "_tblgeo".

Comment: If anyone would be so please to copy and paste: I have tested it on freemyslq hosting and found that the problem was my SQL query the data is only is "small" letters hence _tblGeo should have been "_tblgeo". I will mark the question as answered since I cannot answer my own question since I am new. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Per the asker's request:

*I have tested it on freemyslq hosting and found that the problem was my SQL query the data is only is "small" letters hence _tblGeo should have been "_tblgeo".*